# Cordova cannot add a platform, Nothing Happens

Tags: android, cordova, platform

I am absolutely going crazy here!
I had cordova happily working and pushing builds to my devices, however I tried to update Android Studio and something went very wrong and now none of it works.

I have followed this to the letter to "start again" but keep getting stuck at the bit where I add a platform, nothing happens and then any subsequent commands obviously fail.

http://fiznool.com/blog/2017/05/30/a-guide-to-installing-cordova-on-windows-10/

```
C:\Apps\hello>cordova platform add android --verbose
No scripts found for hook "before_platform_add".
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2
saving
Running command: cmd "/s /c ""C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd" install 
cordova-android@~6.2.2 --save""

C:\Apps\hello>cordova platform list
Installed platforms:

Available platforms:
  android ~6.2.2
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~4.1.0
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
{}

C:\Apps\hello>cordova platform add android
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2

C:\Apps\hello>cordova platform list
Installed platforms:

Available platforms:
  android ~6.2.2
  blackberry10 ~3.8.0 (deprecated)
  browser ~4.1.0
  webos ~3.7.0
  windows ~5.0.0
 {}
```

I have tried all the nofetch business but although that lets me get past the platform issue, nothing happens after that

```
'$' C:\Apps\hello>cordova platform add android@6.2.3 --nofetch
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms\android
    Package: com.example.hello
    Name: HelloWorld
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-25
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Android project created with cordova-android@6.2.3
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

C:\Apps\hello>cordova platform list

C:\Apps\hello>cordova platform list

C:\Apps\hello>npm --version
5.3.0

 C:\Apps\hello>cordova build android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144

C:\Apps\hello>cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Ben\AppData\Local\Android\sdk1
```

Honestly I have no idea what I am doing here now

Please help

Comment: try to reinstall cordova with npm install cordova -g

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric, but that doesnt work:

Comment: C:\Apps\poo2>cordova platform add android
     Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2

     C:\Apps\poo2>cordova build android
     Error: No platforms added to this project. Please use `cordova 
     platform add <platform>`.

Comment: The one thing that gets me closer is putting an older version of cordova on, i.e. not 7.0.1 but maybe 6.5.0 but that then stops anything running

Comment: I have come back to this after a month or so and still cant get anything going, I dont suppose anyone out there is able to help???

Comment: OK, so after another 4 hours I finally fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

OK in the interest of keeping this useful I finally fixed it, this is what I did if it helps anyone:

1. Uninstall cordova npm uninstall -g cordova
2. Delete the .cordova file from C:/users/[username]/
3. Uninstall node.js
4. Re-install node js
5. Make sure the environment variables are all correct (Importantly add the C;/windows/system32 to the PATH)
6. Re-install cordova
7. cordova platform add android

This worked only in this specific order and now all is back together again.
It is very fiddly especially the environment variables and if you are new to this.

I hope this helps or at least guides someone